# Removing scientific notation from IJulia outputs?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab

How do I remove scientific notation from Jupyter/IJulia outputs and only get the raw floating point number?
[image]

Comment: Hi there! It would be helpful if you provide a minimal working example - that is, code that someone can actually run to reproduce your problem - rather than a screenshot. You can probably just do `a = [rand() * 10^i for i in 1:10]` - for me, that starts generating scientific notation at the 6th place (in the REPL too, not just in Jupyter)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `@printf` macro from the [Printf](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/) module in the Standard Library to control the printing of float values. This macro takes as it's first argument a string containing format specifiers:

```
julia> using Printf

julia> x = 1.23456e8
1.23456e8

julia> @printf "x is equal to %f .\n" x
x is equal to 123456000.000000 .
```

Here the `%f` format specifier says to print the number as a float, which defaults to 6 digits to the right of the decimal. There are various flags or sub-specifiers that you can use to adjust the print output. If you only want to have two digits to the right of the decimal, you could use `%.2f` instead:

```
julia> @printf "x is equal to %.2f .\n" x
x is equal to 123456000.00 .
```

For more information on the format specifiers, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 6):

the Formatting package can also help:

```
julia> x = 1.23456e8
1.23456e8

julia> using Formatting

julia> format(x)
"123456000"

julia> format(x, commas=true)
"123,456,000"
```